# Can cured concrete be re-colored?

Tags: concrete

The well cured concrete stamped driveway was lightly rained on one morning. I was late for work and proceeded to spin the tires.  Later I saw the repercussions of my haste. The spinning tire left a tread mark; not black from melting rubber, but a pale one. The release agent/dye  used to stamp the design into the cement had been lifted and removed. My question is: how can I remove or hide this mark? Can cured concrete be re-stained? will it fade eventually? It has been sealed once  before the tire mark.

Comment: "Without being very alert *I floored the accelerator*"  - Definitely a Cali driver. LOL. 

From the sounds of it, you probably took the seal coat off the top, can you post a picture?

Comment: yeah I'm hysterical. The tire erased  the colored release agent. This means the rest of the concrete is colored while the tire mark is pale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track down the fellows that installed the concrete driveway. He stated that if the concrete has been sealed it would be almost impossible (expensive) to get any color to adhere properly. He went on to say that I could 2 part epoxy the surface, but that too will eventually wear out. I'm thinking about pressure washing the surface. I'll do a small area as a test run. If nothing else I will try to remove the sealer and coloring to match the tire mark.